# recursion - return ( method (...) || method (...) )

Tags: java

Can someone explain to me what the "or"(||) mean when we doing the next return?

**I meant this line:**

`return cover (values, amount - values [index], index + 1) || cover (values, amount, index + 1);`

```
public static boolean cover (int[] values, int amount) {
      return  cover(values,amount,0);
}

private static boolean cover (int[] values, int amount, int index) {
    if (index >= values.length || amount == 0)
        return (amount == 0);
    else
        return cover(values, amount - values[index], index+1)||cover(values, amount, index + 1);

}
```

Comment: Look at the return type of `cover(int[], int, int)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return cover(values, amount - values[index], index+1)||cover(values, amount, index + 1);
```

The above statement is the same as:

```
boolean result1 = cover(values, amount - values[index], index+1);
if(!result1) {
    return cover(values, amount, index + 1);
} else {
    return true;
}
```

When `||` is being evaluated, the second part does not get executed when the first part evaluates to true. So, if the first call to `cover()` returns true, the second call is not made.

Answer (score 1):

```
return cover (values, amount - values [index], index + 1) || cover (values, amount, index + 1);
```

this will return `true` if either `cover (values, amount - values [index], index + 1)` returns `true` (if this happens it won't bother with the second call) or `cover (values, amount, index + 1)` returns `true`

Answer (score 1):

Java evaluates the first clause, if it returns true then Java does not evaluate the second clause. If the first clause returns false, then Java evaluates the second clause.

In short: if `cover(values, amount - values [index], index + 1)` returns true, `cover(values, amount, index + 1)` is not executed. If `cover(values, amount - values [index], index + 1)` returns false, `cover(values, amount, index + 1)` is executed. The result will be true if at least one of them returns true

Answer (score 0):

It's a boolean disjunction. I'm not familar with the specific algorithm in question, but in the else branch you want to return whether one expression OR the other (or both) returns true.

```
private static boolean cover (int[] values, int amount, int index) {
    if (index >= values.length || amount == 0)
        return (amount == 0);
    else
        // First boolean expression OR second boolean expression
        return cover(values, amount - values[index], index+1)||cover(values, amount, index + 1);
```

Conceptually, another way of doing this (without short-circuit evaluation*) would have been:

```
private static boolean cover (int[] values, int amount, int index) {
    if (index >= values.length || amount == 0)
        return (amount == 0);
    else {
        boolean expr1 = cover(values, amount - values[index], index+1);
        boolean expr2 = cover(values, amount, index + 1);

        if (expr1 == true) return true;
        if (expr2 == true) return true;

        // None of them are true, so return false
        return false;
    }
```

Although the second way is clearly overly verbose and you can do it in a cleaner way by using the disjunction operator (||) which will do the same thing.

*Note that in the initial example, using the disjunction operator there is a case of short-circuit evaluation. That means that if the first operand of the operation returns "true", we never need to evaluate the second operand. This makes the overall expression more efficient and in recursive algorithms such as this it can make a significant difference in performance.

Comment: Actually, the `||` in the original can short-circuit, which means that it's possible that only the first call to `cover` will execute.  In your second example, you guarantee that both will execute.

Comment: That's correct. I added a clarification. Thank you!